# HTML List with two floated divs inside doesn't display correctly

Tags: css

This is my code

```
<ul style="list-style-type: circle; margin-left:70px;">
<li >
    <a style="">
        <div style="border:1px solid green;float:left">asdsd</div>
        <div style="border:1px solid blue;float:left">.............</div>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

For some reason the list circle appears over the text and not to left of it.

I suspect it's the two floated divs that are the culprits. I've tried my usual solution for this with another div with style="clear:both", but that didn't work either.

This is driving me crazy...

Edit: 
The reason I have divs in a list is that I need to use this code for my jquery UI autocomplete which I need to divide into columns (the divs in my code)
This was the only way I could do that. Without the circle everything works great. But with the circle...

Comment: Why would you put divs, and moreover floating divs inside a li element?

Comment: it does not appear on text for me http://tinkerbin.com/j6HOvDzh

Comment: Updated the question to clarify.
SRN: I see the dot over the text "......" and Not to the left of the text.

Comment: @AndreasLarsson that is because there is only one list item and only one circle appears, put your "...." text in another list item

Comment: @KayKay There's no reason not to put floating divs in a <li> element. Check out the source code to Facebook's news feed for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd advise breaking the CSS out into another file. Displaying the divs as inline-block rather than floating them will deliver a similar look. Here's a JS Fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mMQBy/

Answer (score 0):

You can't put block element in inline element (`<div>` in `<a>`).
You will have to repeat your `<a>` inside of each `<div>`
Than use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left;` on your `<div>`.
**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/hJfUF/